# Prove $f(x)=x^2+6x+12$ is increasing on $[-3,\infty)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Prove $f(x)=x^2+6x+12$ is increasing on $[-3,\infty)$

I have to prove using the definition of increasing that if $a<b$ then $f(a)<f(b)$
If you take an arbitrary $(a,b)$ in $[-3,\infty)$ how would you proceed to prove that $f(a)<f(b)$

Comment: What did you try? Did you try to write $f(b)-f(a)$?

Answer (score 3):

Let $ a<b \in [-3,+\infty)$.

$f(a)-f(b)=(a-b)(a+b+6)$

so

$a\geq -3$ and $b> -3$

$\implies a+b+6>0$

$\implies f(a)-f(b)<0$

$\implies f$ is increasing at $[-3,+\infty)$.

Comment: guys, he asked "how would you proceed" not please solve this for me :/

Answer (score 1):

Note that $x^{2} + 6x + 12 = (x+3)^{2} + 3$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, so $(-3,3)$ is the vertex of the curve curving toward the positive orientation of the ordinate. Note that $a>b \geq -3$ implies $(a+3)^{2} > (b+3)^{2}$.

Comment: This is not a "proof using the definition" OP asks for.

Comment: @Abstraction, have you checked my edited version?

Comment: To OP: Through the first line I'd like to show you sometimes geometric "intuition" is quite helpful :).

Answer (score 0):

you write $f(a)-f(b)$=...

then you assume that $a-b<0$ and use this and logic

and creating more $=$'s and $<$'s untill you can put $<0$

and be carefully not to end up too far away, you may reach a conclusion that ...$<5$ which will be true but don't prove anything.

alternatively you may prove that $$\forall_{a<x<b } f'(x)>0 \Rightarrow f\,is\,increasing\,on\,(a,b)$$

or that a quadratic function $x^2+px+q$ is increasing for $x>s$ where $x=s$ is axis of symmetry

there are also numerous other approaches